# CFString allocations issue using ARC

Tags: ios, image, memory-management, nsfilemanager, cfstring

In my application I am dealing with uploading of images. My images are in documents directory.
I am using `NSFileManager` to get the data from it and converting to base 64 encoding. 
Everything goes good while uploading. But after successful uploading of images it shows 100MB allocations out of which around 54MB are shown for `CFString`. Can anybody guide me for the reason of `CFString` allocation?

Code snippet:

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSFileManager *fileMngr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

  NSString *strZipPath= [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip",strRandomFolderName]];
  NSData *dat=[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:strZipPath];
  NSString *strZipEncoded =[dat encodeBase64ForData];
```

strZipEncoded is sent to server using webmethod.

Please find images for more information.

Thanks.

[image: allocations]

[image: cfstring]

Comment: Can you add some of your code please?

Comment: You can use Instruments to show what's responsible for doing all those CFString allocations.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann
 As my second image shows responsible is only foundation and no other detail info given related to my code.

Comment: @ Janak Nirmal I updated the question please check the code.

Comment: What are you doing inside `encodeBase64ForData` ?

Comment: It's classes for encoding taken from github. NSData+Base64Additions.m

Comment: To add more to this I am using NSMutableString and appendformat to create soap envelope for web method.

Comment: May I get any hint on this? :(